# Android: hide / show table rows

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have a table layout (a form with real estate filtering parameters). I need to hide/show rows with filtering parameters when user selects realty type from `Spinner` list (apartment, house, land etc.). Is it possible? Is TableLayout good for that or would it be better to use LinearLayout? When it's better to use TableLayout over LinearLayout?
I have a simple table with horizontal form which looks like this:

```
-------------------------
field name: [input field]
-------------------------
field name: [input field]
-------------------------
```

I already found that I can remove / add rows:

```
tableLayout.addView(row);
tableLayout.removeView(row);
```

Is it the only one way to go? Can I just hide/show rows without removing them?

Comment: i do the exact thing you are asking about in one app. Assuming the TableRow has an id, and a variable is assigned to it (findViewById()) then <variable_name>.setVisibility(View.GONE) or (View.VISIBLE) will do the trick. no repositioning.

Comment: @DavidM - I just tried it and yes I can hide rows now but there are gaps between rows. Invisible rows doesn't collapse, they leave blank gap. How can I solve that?

Comment: @DavidM if you have an answer please post it as answer (not a comment) so I can accept it

Comment: hmmm. i haven't noticed that in my app. could you post the layout?

Comment: @DavidM oh sorry! it was my mistake - I used `View.INVISIBLE` instead of `View.GONE`. Now there are no gaps! Thank you! Will you post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `<variable>.setVisible(View.GONE)` and `<variable>.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)` to hide and show a tableRow variable. There will be no need to reposition the row(s).

Good luck!